# How can I roll back/restore the previous data if I don't click "save" the record in an editable react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have created an editable table with react-table V7. It is fine in the saving function.
However, I got an issue with the cancel function. I don't how to roll back/ restore to initial value in the following situation.

1. Users click the "cancel" button.
2. Users click the other "Edit" button in edit mode.

I have a sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jang-6e5f2b?file=/src/components/EnhancedTable.js

Comment: Presumably you have one "real" value and one value for the input. When someone cancels, restore the real value.

Comment: @super which component should I save the "real" value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef()` to create a snapshot of the current state by going into edit mode and then you should update it only when the <kbd>save</kbd> button is clicked, otherwise rollback state to that snapshot.

Comment: Would you mind showing a sample code?